# Scan Remote FTP server (Akamai) for files, use filename to create content

Tags: media, files

I'm wondering if there is an existing workflow to achieve what I'm looking for before I'm forced to go and build my own.  This is, preferably, in drupal 7.

I have media files stored on an akamai server that need to be scanned either via a cron or manual start and after they're scanned, their filenames need to be put into separate content.  I do not need the files individually parsed, I just need the filenames added to title and add the filename to a textbox within the created content.

I have found a few methods that sound similar to what I'm looking for such as:
- Storage API: Does connect, but cannot find files that were not uploaded via their service.
- File Field Sources: No remote FTP, but does scan local and such.
- Bulk Media Upload: Does scan and create a new node for each, does not do remote.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

How about [feeds](https://www.drupal.org/project/feeds)?

<sub>(Sorry this would/should be a comment but I don't have enough rep yet)</sub>